# Best Multilingual Wordpress Solution with the Best SEO Practices at the Forefront

Tags: ajax, wordpress, seo, wordpress-theming, multilingual

I'm looking to start a Wordpress solution that will answer the following problems:

**Multilingual**

- sitename.com/en/content1
- sitename.com/es/content1
- sitename.com/fr/content1

At first, the articles should be dynamically created using Google translate (I've seen plugins for this somewhere) - based on the English post or page.

Another requirement is that I will need to replace the dynamic content with correctly translated static content at a later date. So I will need to manually override the content pages for the relevant country.

**SEO**

The final requirement, is that the whole platform needs to be as good as possible when it comes to SEO. I'm essentially targeting many countries / regions and keyword targeting will be of paramount importance.

**AJAX**

The site will most likely incorporate AJAX. I'm aware that this could throw up possible problems

I understand this is quite a unique problem and there could be a number of solutions, but I'm simply seeking some advice,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Wordpress is not the perfect solution for multilingual pages, since it does not support this out of the box.

But if you need to use Wordpress, I would recommend PolyLang. It pretty much does what you want. Ajax has nothing to do with this issue.

For Wordpress questions I would recommend Wordpress development. There is already a discussion on this topic:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/open-source-replacement-for-wpml/52025#52025

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I'll look into this.

P.S. What's with the downvotes from everyone? This site is seriously turning to shit

Comment: No idea why we got the downvotes. Voted yours up again. So it's at least neutral.